# Extract lzma compressed tar archive members without writing to disk

Tags: python, lzma, tarfile

I have a nested tar file 2 tars deep. The outermost tar is gpg encrypted and not compressed. The inner tar is lzma. Working with the innermost tar from disk I don't have any problems. Passing the inner most tar.xz file directly to `with tarfile.open() as get_lzma` works. The code following that line executes without error. I can extract the tar members and `json.load()` the data.

It's a small file, the data is sensitive. It has to sit on disk while I work with it so I don't want to decrypt it and extract the innermost tar to disk. So I'd like to access the members in memory. I can decrypt to the gpg file and `for member in get_lzma.getmembers():` returns the tarinfo objects I'd expect, so the member appears to be there, I just can't do anything with it. When I run `extractfile()` I can't `.read()` the result as it returns `<ExFileObject name=None>`.

At this point I'm just curious as the why this isn't work.

In case the file structure is unclear this is how it's sitting on disk:

```
file.tar.gpg <- is a tar file
 file.tar.xz <- is a compressed tar file
   member1
   memberN
```

```
   json.load(file_o)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/tarfile.py", line 681, in read
    self.fileobj.seek(offset + (self.position - start))
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/lzma.py", line 253, in seek
    return self._buffer.seek(offset, whence)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/_compression.py", line 143, in seek
    data = self.read(min(io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE, offset))
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/_compression.py", line 103, in read
    data = self._decompressor.decompress(rawblock, size)
_lzma.LZMAError: Input format not supported by decoder
```

```
   with open(gpg_encrypted_tar_archive, 'rb') as f: 
        try:
            decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt_file(f, passphrase=passph)
            assert decrypted_data.ok
        except AssertionError:
            print(f"Decryption failed with message '{decrypted_data.status}' and status '{decrypted_data.ok}'")

        io_bytes_file_like_object = io.BytesIO(decrypted_data.data)

        # untar the parent archive
        tarfile.open(fileobj=io_bytes_file_like_object, mode='r')

        with tarfile.open(fileobj=io_bytes_file_like_object, mode='r:xz', debug=3, errorlevel=2) as get_lzma:

            for member in get_lzma.getmembers():

                if member.isfile():
                    file_o = get_lzma.extractfile(member)
                    json.load(file_o)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A day away from this issue seems to have cleared up my understanding of the problem. I'll explain my thinking and what I found.

tldr I got my tarinfo and tarfile and exfileobjects all mixed up.

As per OP the files passed to `open()` are represented as `<_io.BufferedReader name='myfile.tar.xz'>` under the covers. So getting the code to work with the unencrypted file and `open()`, really only proves that the file wasn't corrupted. So no issues there, I won't mention it again.

Following the code example in the OP, calling `decrypted_data.data` returns a raw byte string from the `decrypted_data` object. These raw bytes are my 2 tar files. The uncompress tar and the compressed tar nested structure. The string starts `b'myfile.tar.xz\x00\x00\x00\......` etc. We wrap this us as a bytes object `io.BytesIO(decrypted_data.data)` so that we have an interface to work with and so it can be passed to `tarfile.open()` initally. So far so good, but that's where things started to go wrong.

I've decided to go with 2 context managers in the following code. In the OP I made a call to `tarfile.open()` twice, I guess I must have assumed that there was an extraction operation along with `mode='r'`. You can see that I now make 2 calls to `extractfile()` on the `member`'s of each context manager. The first `extractfile()` extracting the tar.xz from the uncompressed tar. This is the `ExFileObject` "file" I eventually pass to the next context manager as `mode=r:xz`. In the OP it'd have been a `TarInfo` object, not the extracted data, which is wrong.

The second call to `extractfile()` is done on `member` of the second context manager in order to get `readable_members_value` from `myfile.tar.xz`.

```
with tarfile.open(fileobj=io_bytes_file_like_object, mode='r') as uncompressed_tar_file:

    # uncompressed_tar_file is tarfile.TarFile object
    for member in uncompressed_tar_file.getmembers():

      # member is TarInfo object
        tar_file_object = uncompressed_tar_file.extractfile(member)

        # tar_file_object is ExFileObject
        with tarfile.open(fileobj=tar_file_object, mode='r:xz', debug=3, errorlevel=2) as lzma_compressed_tar_file:
            for member in lzma_compressed_tar_file.getmembers():
                if member.isfile():
                    readable_members_value = lzma_compressed_tar_file.extractfile(member)

                    # now works where it failed before equivalent to something like file_o.read() in OP
                    print(readable_members_value.read())

                    decoded_readable_member_value = readable_member_value.read().decode("utf-8")
                    json_data = json.loads(decoded_readable_member_value)
                    print(json_data)
```

The rest of the code is pretty much identical apart from the last few lines. You can see by the variable names in OP I was expecting `file_o` to be a file object. `json.load(file_o)` would work against a file pointer but in this case `readable_member.read()` is returning bytes literal `b''` so it's actually `json.loads()` that I need not `json.load()`.